# Determining Permutation Equation Solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

[image]

[image]

I need to find which permutation equation has the most solutions among $\pi^{2021} = \alpha$, $\pi^{2022} = \alpha$, and $\pi^{2025} = \alpha$. I suspect that $\pi^{2022} = \alpha$ might have the most solutions.

I observed that when I wrote the permutation as disjoint cycles: $(1\ 9\ 3)$ $(2\ 4\ 5)$ $(6\ 8\ 7)$, each cycle has a length of $3$. Thinking about these disjoint cycles, if I distribute the exponent $2022$ among them (2<sup>nd</sup> equation), it results in an identity, suggesting possibly $2022$ solutions for the 2<sup>nd</sup> equation, if my reasoning is correct.

To determine the number of solutions for the other two equations, $\pi^{2021}= \alpha$ and $\pi^{2025} = \alpha$, I'm looking for a method to count their solutions. Once I figure out the solutions for all three equations, I can compare and find out which one has the most solutions.

Comment: Determine the order $k$ of $\alpha$ in $S_9$. Then $\alpha^k=id$, so $\pi^{2021\cdot k}=id$ etc.Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cycles of $\pi$ must be some combination of the cycles of $\alpha$. There are three possibilities.

If $\pi$ is a single $9$-cycle, then the exponent must be a multiple of $3$ but not of $9$, which leaves only $2022$. Then, since $2022\equiv6\bmod9$, the $9$-cycle must have the form $(1\ x\ x\ 3\ x\ x\ 9\ x\ x)$. There are $6$ spots to choose for the $2$ (also fixing $4$ and $5$), and then $3$ spots to choose for the $6$ (also fixing $8$ and $7$), for a total of $6\cdot3=18$ solutions to $\pi^{2022}=\alpha$.

If $\pi$ has three $3$-cycles, the exponent must not be a multiple of $3$, which leaves only $2021$. There are no free choices; the three cycles of $\pi$ must be the inverses/squares of the cycles of $\alpha$ (since $2021\equiv2\bmod3$), so this only yields one solution to $\pi^{2021}=\alpha$.

Finally, if $\pi$ has one $3$-cycle and one $6$-cycle, for the $3$-cycle to survive the exponentiation the exponent must not be a multiple of $3$, which leaves only $2021$, but for the $6$-cycle to split into two $3$-cycles the exponent must be a multiple of $2$ but not of $6$. Since $2021$ is not a multiple of $2$, this doesn’t yield any solutions.

To summarize: There are $18$ solutions to $\pi^{2022}=\alpha$, one solution to $\pi^{2021}=\alpha$ and no solutions at all to $\pi^{2025}=\alpha$, so your suspicion is vindicated.